# Is it possible to get Magento 1.9x running bug free with HHVM?

Tags: magento-1.9, hhvm

I'd like to get my shop running faster, and have been playing with HHVM but I've run into all sorts of bugs when using it.

Is it possible to get it to work cleanly, or is Magento 1.9x just not ready for HHVM (or visa-versa)?

Comment: Would php7 not be a more viable option?

Comment: I don't know. I'm very new to Magento.. and php. Is Magento more compatible with php7 and is the speed better?

Comment: all you have to do just enable error log and post it here

Comment: Php7 is a LOT faster that previous versions. Is it faster than hhvm, i dont know. Will ot be easier to get magento working on php7 than hhvm - most likely.

Comment: there are lot of people who still dont understand the difference php7 stack and hhmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run roughly 100 shops (different versions and extensions) in HHVM and all of them crash at least occasionally (segfault), even with the latest stable HHVM release.

HHVM is younger and has a (much) smaller install base than PHP, therefore it is less mature. And with the great speed improvements of PHP 7 I do not suspect that its usage will increase. Fwiw, at Hypernode we urge our customers to [switch to PHP 7](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/upgrading-hhvm-php7/).

Comment: do you actually understand the technical difference between hhvm and php stack? you probably right if the shop is small and has no decent traffic, then ok php7 stack is good to go, but when you have autoscaling configured and your server farm expands in few seconds upto 5 instances, then i would rather make it compatible with hhvm, it will save me a fortune and i dont have to drink `valeriana` during TV campaign.

Comment: @MagenX please elaborate. Why would HHVM enable autoscaling and PHP7 not? Both in our lab benchmarks and production setups we see comparable performance with both stacks.

Comment: i am saying that with hhvm i can run 2 servers, while 1k users seamlessly go to checkout. with php 7 stack, instances will continue to scale up endlessly.

Comment: If that is true, both the HHVM guys and me would love to see your substantiated benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get Magento 1 running very well with HHVM and there are some well known hosting companies that offer it too.

Two gotchas I remember when configuring HHVM for Magento was that you need to add the following to /etc/hhvm/php.ini

```
; enable the support for Zend PHP alike sort stability
hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1
; enable hhvm to call destructors for objects
hhvm.enable_obj_destruct_call = 1
```

For more information on using HHVM checkout this excellent [MageTitans talk from Daniel Sloof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfTx2hWgylM&feature=youtu.be). You can get the [slides here](http://www.slideshare.net/meetmagento/daniel-sloof-magento-on-hhvm).

I also used NGINX rather than Apache2 for my webserver.

I'm don't think Magento 1 supports php7 but Magento 2 does, see... https://magento.com/blog/technical/new-magento-20-resources-and-support-php7

Comment: We did hire Daniel Sloof for a couple of months to help make HHVM more compatible with Magento. However, the sheer number of libxml issues was unfortunately overwhelming. 
Mag1 doesn't support PHP7 out of the box, but with Inchoo's module it does for versions 1.9 and up -- https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7